# Compare multiple files

Tags: file-comparison, bash-script

I want a bash-script to compare OR find differences for multiple files which are stored in different locations:

Files under `/tmp/test/`

- A.txt
- B.txt
- C.txt

Compare with files under `/home/oldtest`/

- A.txt
- B.txt
- C.txt

#### Condition:

1. File `/tmp/test/A.txt` compare only with `/home/oldtest/A.txt` (similarly for other files - `B.txt` compare with `B.txt`).
2. If any changes found: status should be "Modification require in file A.txt".

Answer (score 7):

`diff` from GNU diffutils has an option for recursive compare:

```
diff -qrs /dir/A /dir/B
```

compares the directories: `-q` quietly (i.e. no differences are printed, it only reports that files differ), `-r` recursively (complete trees with all subdirectories), `-s` reporting identical files.

Comment: add | grep -v "identical" to skip all the file identical messages

Comment: @JustinMclean it should read `| grep -v ' are identical$'`, unless you want to discard any difference information about files that contain "identical" in their name. Plus, if you omit the `-s` option, you'll get the same result without the additional process.

Comment: Yes omitting -s would be simpler.

Answer (score 5):

```
cd /tmp/test
for i in *.txt; do diff -q $i /home/oldtest/$i; done
```

The output will be "Files A.txt and ../home/oldtest/A.txt differ" for each file that has a difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /tmp/test/;
for x in *; do \
  cmp -s "$x" /home/oldtest/"$x" || echo "Modification required in file $x";
done;|more
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if someone will just write you a script but you can get similar functionality using `diff`. Just use `diff -q`.

For instance:

```
$ diff -q .vimrc .bashrc
Files .vimrc and .bashrc differ
```

If you want to automate that you can, using a script.

For a good reference on learning how to write bash scripts take a look here: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Main_Page